# How to insert into accounts when signing up

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express

I am implementing a web-app using a **three layered architecture** with **express** and **docker**. I am also using **mysql** to store accounts. This is my **initialize-database.sql** file:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
    personId INT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (personId)
)
```

In my data-access layer I have the **account-repository** file that sends queries to the database:

```
const db = require('./db')
exports.createAccount = function(account, callback){

    const query = "INSERT INTO accounts (email, userPassword) VALUES (?, ?)"
    const values = [account.email, account.userPassword]
    console.log("account:", account)
    db.query(query, values, function(error, results){
        if(error){
            callback("DatabaseError", null)
        }else{
            callback([], results.insertId)
        }
    })
}
```

Now in my **app.js** file I want to insert the username and password when the user is signing up:

```
app.post('/signup', function(request, response){

    const email = request.body.email
    const userPassword = request.body.userPassword
    const message = []
    if(email && userPassword){
        account.createAccount(email, userPassword, function(error, account){
            if(error){
                response.send("<h1>Error with database</h1>")
            }
            else if(account.length > 0){
                console.log(account)
                message.push("Thank you for signing up, now you can log in!")
                const model = {
                    message
                }
                response.render("start.hbs", model)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

When submitting the form it just loads then crashes, then shows this **Error:** *Got an error reading communication packets*. Anyone knows what causing this?
  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have too many connections to your data base 
so increase

> max_allowed_packet

and/or

> max_connections

but before that take a look at

```
show status like '%onn%';
```

and

```
show processlist;
```

to  see what is going on on your server.